# Null Pointer Excpetion when trying to test if array is empty java

Tags: java, arrays, nullpointerexception

I was tyring to test if my array is empty, but I always get a null pointer exception for some reason. I don't understand since my test actually test if the value is null. Here is the code where it gets stucks. I get the null pointer on the While loop:

```
private int findIndex(String key) {
        int index = calculateHashCode(key);
        while (table[index] != null && !table[index].getKey().equals(key)) {
            index = (index + 1) % TABLE_SIZE;
        }
        return index;
    }
```

**EDIT**

table is declared like this:

```
static HashEntry[] table;
```

Comment: Where is `table` declared? It's likely that `table` is null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `table` is `null`. The act of performing `table[index]` dereferences the array, which causes a `NullPointerException`. A null array is not a empty array. A null array roughly corresponds to that fact that there is no array at all, and the `table` variable points to nothing.

Please make the distinction between a null array, an empty array and a null element in a non-empty array.

Array is null:

```
table == null
```

Array is empty:

```
table.length == 0
```

Element 0 in array is null:

```
table[0] == null
```

Similarly, you cannot call methods from a `null` object. If `table[index]` returns a null element, calling getKey() upon it could result in `NullPointerException`. Same goes if getKey() is null and then trying to call equals() on that.

Please note an uninitialized array is implicitly `null`. Make sure you actually initialize the array.

Answer (score 2):

The NullPointer Exception could be because either:

1. `table` is null, or
2. `table[index].getKey()` returns null

In case 1, the evaluation of the expression `table[index] != null` is a read of an item from the table array.  This will throw a NullPointerException if table is null.

In case 2, if `table[index].getKey()` returns null, then the expression `table[index].getKey().equals(key)` is calling a method (equals) on a null object reference which results in the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Your `table` isn't initialised, declare as

```
static HashEntry[] table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];
```

so that it isn't null.

Also, if `HashEntry.getKey()` can return `null`, make sure you check for this (or just flip the equals, i.e. `!key.equals(table[index].getKey())`